# How to use Graphic Buttons

Tags: html, css

I am new to styling. When I was searching for styling buttons, I came to know about this "Graphic Button". How do I include graphic buttons in my page.

Answer (score 3):

```
<button type="button">
    <img src="graphic.png" alt="alternative text">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use css and go through background etc, example, just to show you how much you can do

```
.btn, input[type="button"] {
    /*border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.8125rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    background: none;
    /*border-color: #2bacd1;*/
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;*/
    /*-webkit-transition: background-color 100ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 100ms ease-out;
    transition: background-color 100ms ease-out;*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    min-width: 95px;
}
```